# Форма Ф.И.О. на php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такая страничка регистрации,нужно что бы все отправлялось по форме в базу,по моей глупости и незнамке, при вводе поля ФИО, которое должно быть вида :Иванов И.И. он выдает ошибку о том, что можно использовать буквы только русского алфавита(оно и понятно), но, даже если не использовать точки и пробелы, все аналогично.
Был бы признателен за подсказку, подозреваю, что все дело в 20 строке:

`if(!preg_match("/^[а-яА-Я]/",$_POST['fullname']))`

```html
<?php

$link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "usersdb");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $err = [];

    // проверям логин и фио
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/",$_POST['login']))
    {
        $err[] = "Логин может состоять только из букв английского алфавита и цифр";
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['login']) < 3 or strlen($_POST['login']) > 30)
    {
        $err[] = "Логин должен быть не меньше 3-х символов и не больше 30";
    }

    if(!preg_match("/^[а-яА-Я]/",$_POST['fullname']))
    {
        $err[] = "Ф.И.О может состоять только из букв Русского алфавита";
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['fullname']) < 3 or strlen($_POST['fullname']) > 50)
    {
        $err[] = "Ф.И.О. должно быть не меньше 3-х символов и не больше 50";
    }

    // проверяем, не сущестует ли пользователя с таким именем
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['login'])."'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        $err[] = "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует в базе данных";
    }
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_fullname='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['fullname'])."'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        $err[] = "Пользователь с таким Ф.И.О уже существует в базе данных";
    }

    // Если нет ошибок, то добавляем в БД нового пользователя
    if(count($err) == 0)
    {
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $login = $_POST['login'];

        // Убераем лишние пробелы и делаем двойное хеширование
        $password = md5(md5(trim($_POST['password'])));

        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO users SET user_login='".$login."', user_password='".$password."', user_fullname='".$fullname."'");
        header("Location: index.php"); exit();
    }
    else
    {
        print "<b>При регистрации произошли следующие ошибки:</b><br>";
        foreach($err AS $error)
        {
            print $error."<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Странно, ведь эта регулярка проверяет только самую первую букву. Начиная  со второй там может быть всё, что угодно..

Comment: двойное хеширование md5 - ничем не лучше одинарного или никакого.

Comment: @vp_arth Ты о ? /^[а-яА-Я]+$/

Comment: Скорее всего. Однако оно также не очень полезно для ввода ФИО. Cкорее, что-то вроде `/^[а-я]+\s*[a-я]\.?[а-я]\.?$/ui` У вас же charset=utf-8?

Comment: @vp_arth Абсолютно верно

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо огромное! Вроде бы стало работать!)

Comment: `"Пользователь с таким Ф.И.О уже существует в базе данных"` У нас в стране очень много полных тёзок.

Comment: @vp_arth Может я могу тогда еще с одним вопрос обратиться, так же для этого решения. Условно если бы пароль и логин были Administrator/administrator что бы был редирект на отдельную страницу?
В остальном что бы можно было "брать" из базы?

Comment: @vp_arth Это сугубо локальная программка для отчета ) И кто в нее сможет залезть - единицы )

Comment: Лучше добавьте отдельное поле для роли пользователя. А потом проверяйте, если $user['role']==='admin', то редирект. (не забыв аутентифицировать пользователя, например в сессии и проверить авторизацию(роль/доступ) на целевой странице)

Comment: Хороший стиль нужно прививать сразу, рано или поздно вам придётся писать что-то более серьёзное, а привычки останутся. =)

Comment: @vp_arth Связаться как-то можно?) на пару вопросов

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. Пару вопросов лучше [задайте тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Да просто роли добавил уже, и хотел конкретно спросить, как интегрировать, что если user_role = 1 то редирект на одну страницу, если user_role = 2 , то на другую.

Comment: Ну вот так и спросите, отдельным вопросом. Я тут не один)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cкорее всего у вас кодировка utf-8, поэтому нужно использовать модификатор u

Для ФИО в формате `Иванов И.И.` будет что-то вроде:

```
$pattern = '/^[а-я]+\s+[a-я]\.?[а-я]\.?$/ui';
```

Или, жёстче, с требованием корректного регистра и точек:

```
$pattern = '/^[А-Я][а-я]*\s+[А-Я]\.[А-Я]\.$/u';
```